# How do you join an array of strings and HTML elements in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a list of names that I need to return with commas in between, so normally I'd just use `.join`, but one item in the list will need to have the icon of a star next to it based on if a condition is met, which doesn't work in the join.  Is there something similar to a join that I could use that doesn't turn everything into a string so that it displays the HTML element instead of returning 'name, [Object, object]'?  I tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it continues to just say `name, [Object, object]` instead of `name, <Icon name='star' />name2` with an actual star displaying, not the text for the component.

Comment: You could wrap each name in a ```<span>``` which should allow you to place an ```<Icon />``` as a sibling to the string. Then just render the array of spans like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if Icon is another React element, you should wrap each name is a `<span>` element so that as you loop through the array, you can add the Icon as a sibling to the correct string content.

It could look like this:

```
names.map((name, i) => {
   return <span key={i}>
           { 
            name === focusName ? // However you determine where the star goes
            <Icon name="star" /> :
            null
           }
           { // Add a comma to name if not last item
             name + (i < names.length - 1 ? ',' : '')
           } 
          <span>
});
```